# Error -- Super class constructor in Eclipse with Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, java-8, super

I am coding in eclipse and new to java, inherited method and calling parent method with `super()` keyword showing error in Java-8 also the `new Child();` method is also showing error. File name is Example.java

```
public class Example{
        class Parent{
            void parentMethod(){
                System.out.println("Parent Method");
            }
            void parentMethod(int a){
                    System.out.println("Parent Method: One Argument");
            }
            void parentMethod(int a, int b){
                        System.out.println("Parent Method: Two Argument");
            }
        }
       class Child extends Parent{
            void childMethod() {
                super(10);
                System.out.println("Child Method");
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Child();
            System.out.println("Main Class Method: no argument");
        }
    }
```

it gives an error in eclipse :

```
in line 15: Multiple markers at this line
    - Line breakpoint:Public$Child [line: 15] - 
     childMethod()

in line 20: No enclosing instance of type Public is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing 
 instance of type Public (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Public).
```

.
;
.

Comment: This in not how you declare public class `public class Parent` & `public class Child extends Parent`

Comment: Still getting error

Comment: Why are you using inner classes in the first place? what is the purpose? and what are you trying to do with `super(10);`?

Answer (score 2):

- **`super(10);`** can only be used inside a constructor (not inside a method) to call the constructor of the super class (the class being extended), e.g. if you have `Parent(int a) { ... }`, you can do `Child() { super(10); }`; or if you want to call the existing method of the super class (instead of the non-existing super constructor with a single number parameter) use `super.parentMethod(10);` instead
- **`new Child();`** does not work inside a `static` method for a non-`static` nested class; a non-static inner class belongs to an instance of the outer class: `new Example().new Child();` would work here instead; alternatively, since in the example the nested classes do not make use of instance methods and fields of `Example`, you can make the classes `Parent` and `Child` static to fix the error: `static class Parent{` and `static class Child extends Parent{`